# Can't install Ubuntu 16.04! Display manager Xorg failed

Tags: 16.04, boot, nvidia, system-installation, xorg

I'm trying to install Ubuntu to my laptop Dell inspiron n5110 using USB with MBR scheme , but the installer don't show up and keep getting me that error

```
nouveau ::: Xorg[2133]: falied to idle channel 2
nouveau ::: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0d []
```

I have a nVIDIA GeForce GT525M Graphics I think this the reason. Then the system boot till to reach the login and I can use tty in that situation by using user:ubuntu pass:null, so what shall I do?

**Hint**: I tried to install Mint and it did the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to set the kernel parameter "nomodeset" -  Nomodeset is a kernel parameter that would help you to get the system running. It won't look good ,but once you've installed the proper nvidia drivers everything is fine - and you won't need that parameter anymore.

If you also have an integrated card (ie Intel) that you could switch to in the BIOS Setup - do it. It will save you a lot of trouble. The GT525M is one of the worst cards from nvidia.

Comment: Yeah, I have an Intel HD graphics card, so it can be done through the BIOS before I boot from the USB? that's it